# Link Spring Security to exting Project

Tags: spring, security, hyperlink, parent

I have existing REST API's built into multiple springboot projects. Now would want to enabled JWT for all REST services. I have a separate project which does JWT for a test service. Can that JWT project be linked like a library or associated as a springboot parent to enable spring JWT auth for all REST services which are present in multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details within your question but we also have multiple spring boot services which share common authentication and authorization mechanism (OAuth2.0 authorization token flow + Keycloak + JWT). The implementation of this mehanism is realized as a custom spring boot starter which is the approach I would recommend to you. You can start reading about that, for example, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter).